Text file to csv script
We are using a script that takes in some data and converts it to a csv file, the script we are using is below:
!/bin/bash

  read -p "Enter /DIR/PATH/FILENAME where you wish to copy the data: " FILENAME


 cat test.txt |
    awk '
    BEGIN {
        OFS = ","
        numTags = split("insert_job job_type box_name command machine owner date_conditions condition run_calendar exclude_calendar days_of_week run_window start_times start_mins resources profile term_run_time watch_file watch_interval",tags)
        for ( tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++ ) {
            tag = tags[tagNr]
            printf "\"%s\"%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }

    !NF || /^\/\*/ { next }
    { gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"") }

    match($0,/[[:space:]]job_type:/) {
        if ( jobNr++ ) {
            prt()
            delete tag2val
        }

        # save "insert_job" value
        tag = substr($1,1,length($1)-1)
        val = substr($0,length($1)+1,RSTART-(length($1)+2))
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",val)
        tag2val[tag] = val

        # update $0 to start with "job_type" to look like all other input
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+1)
    }

    {
        tag = val = $0
        sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
        tag2val[tag] = val
    }

    END { prt() }

    function prt(    tagNr,tag,val) {
        for ( tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++ ) {
            tag = tags[tagNr]
            val = tag2val[tag]
            printf "\"%s\"%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
' > $FILENAME.csv

And below is the test data:

$ cat test.txt
/* ----------------- Test_A ----------------- */

insert_job: Test_A  job_type: CMD
command: sleep 3000
machine: machine1
owner: user1
permission:
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: mo,tu,we,th,fr
start_times: “06:00,08:00,10:00,12:00,14:00,16:00”
term_run_time: 1
alarm_if_fail: 1
alarm_if_terminated: 1


/* ----------------- Test_B ----------------- */

insert_job: Test_B    job_type: CMD
command: echo
machine: machine2
owner: user2
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "Test"
std_out_file: "/tmp/$AUTO_JOB_NAME.$AUTORUN.out"
std_err_file: "/tmp/$AUTO_JOB_NAME.$AUTORUN.err"
max_run_alarm: 1
alarm_if_fail: 0
alarm_if_terminated: 0
send_notification: 1



/* ----------------- Test_c ----------------- */

insert_job: Test_c   job_type: CMD
command: sleep 10
machine: machine3
owner: user3
permission:
date_conditions: 0
alarm_if_fail: 0
alarm_if_terminated: 0


/* ----------------- Test_d ----------------- */

insert_job: Test_d   job_type: CMD
command: ls
machine: machine4
owner: user4
permission:
date_conditions: 0
alarm_if_fail: 1
alarm_if_terminated: 1




I’m executing the script I am getting the below results:

"insert_job","job_type","box_name","command","machine","owner","date_conditions","condition","run_calendar","exclude_calendar","days_of_week","run_window","start_times","start_mins","resources","profile","term_run_time","watch_file","watch_interval"
"Test_A","CMD","","sleep 3000","machine1","user1","1","","","","mo,tu,we,th,fr","",""06:00,08:00,10:00,12:00,14:00,16:00"","","","","1","",""
"Test_B","CMD","","echo","machine2","user2","0","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"Test_c","CMD","","sleep 10","machine3","user3","0","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"Test_d","CMD","","ls","machine4","user4","0","","","","","","","","","","","",""


If you see the output I am getting extra "" under start_times column.
The output I am looking for is:

"insert_job","job_type","box_name","command","machine","owner","date_conditions","condition","run_calendar","exclude_calendar","days_of_week","run_window","start_times","start_mins","resources","profile","term_run_time","watch_file","watch_interval"
"Test_A","CMD","","sleep 3000","machine1","user1","1","","","","mo,tu,we,th,fr","","06:00,08:00,10:00,12:00,14:00,16:00","","","","1","",""
"Test_B","CMD","","echo","machine2","user2","0","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"Test_c","CMD","","sleep 10","machine3","user3","0","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"Test_d","CMD","","ls","machine4","user4","0","","","","","","","","","","","",""

What changes do I need to make to the script so it compensates the extra "" in the input data

I Think you should remove [tag:ksh] and add [tag:awk]...

The shebang needs to start with literally the two bytes # and ! to be valid.

Probably avoid the useless use of cat

You need to add gsub(/^"*|"*$/, "", val) to your value extraction in the block below to strip leading or trailing double quotes from the value:
{
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
    gsub(/^"*|"*$/, "", val)
    tag2val[tag] = val
}

Here is your fixed script:
cat test2csv
#!/usr/bin/env -S awk -f

BEGIN {
    OFS = ","
    numTags = split("insert_job job_type box_name command machine owner date_conditions condition run_calendar exclude_calendar days_of_week run_window start_times start_mins resources profile term_run_time watch_file watch_interval",tags)
    for ( tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++ ) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        printf "\"%s\"%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

!NF || /^\/\*/ { next }
{ gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"") }

match($0,/[[:space:]]job_type:/) {
    if ( jobNr++ ) {
        prt()
        delete tag2val
    }

    # save "insert_job" value
    tag = substr($1,1,length($1)-1)
    val = substr($0,length($1)+1,RSTART-(length($1)+2))
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",val)
    tag2val[tag] = val

    # update $0 to start with "job_type" to look like all other input
    $0 = substr($0,RSTART+1)
}

{
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
    # Delete leading or trailing double quotes
    gsub(/^"*|"*$/, "", val)
    tag2val[tag] = val
}

END { prt() }

function prt(tagNr,tag,val) {
    for ( tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++ ) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        val = tag2val[tag]
        printf "\"%s\"%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

Usage:
chmod +x test2csv
./test2csv test.txt



What changes do I need to make to the script so it compensates the
extra "" in the input data

You are doing
printf "\"%s\"%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)

if val already has leading and trailing " you are slapping additional " and thus get ""06:00,08:00,10:00,12:00,14:00,16:00"" to avoid that you might substring val if it starts with " and ends with ". Let file.txt content be
something_without_quotes
"something_in_quotes"
doubled""quote

then
awk '{val=$1;if(val~/^".*"$/){val=substr(val,2,length(val)-2)};printf "\"%s\"\n",val}' file.txt

gives output
"something_without_quotes"
"something_in_quotes"
"doubled""quote"

Explanation: If value in val is starting with " and ending with " I use substr string function to remove 1st and last character by starting at 2nd character and getting substring of length equal to length of original string less 2. For each line I printf value enclosed in ".
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

Not sure if this will work as I don't have time to create a sample project and recreate the bug but if you alter the code:
 tag = val = $0
 sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
 sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
 tag2val[tag] = val

where the split of the values is being done you can alter the tag2val code like the following to escape the characters:
 gsub(/"/, "\"\"", val)
 tag2val[tag] = val

As I said I haven't tested anything.

In this from your input:
start_times: “06:00,08:00,10:00,12:00,14:00,16:00”

Those things that look like double quotes aren't, they are "smart quotes", “ and ”, probably added quietly by some Windows editor you used and so YMMV with what any text processing tool such as awk does with them. Replace those with textual double quotes " as a first step.
Then for your code, you need 2 changes:

When reading the input you need to ensure no value is already wrapped in double quotes since you'll be wrapping all values in double quotes when producing output. So, both places it occurs, change this:

tag2val[tag] = val

to this:
gsub(/^"|"$/,"",val)
tag2val[tag] = val


When printing output you need to ensure that any double quotes remaining mid-val get escaped by doubling them since unescaped double quotes are invalid within a double-quoted CSV field per RFC 4180 (and common sense). So change this:

val = tag2val[tag]

to this:
val = tag2val[tag]
gsub(/"/,"\"\"",val)

Here's the whole updated script:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN {
        OFS = ","
        numTags = split("insert_job job_type box_name command machine owner date_conditions condition run_calendar exclude_calendar days_of_week run_window start_times start_mins resources profile term_run_time watch_file watch_interval",tags)
        for ( tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++ ) {
            tag = tags[tagNr]
            printf "\"%s\"%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }

    !NF || /^\/\*/ { next }
    { gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"") }

    match($0,/[[:space:]]job_type:/) {
        if ( jobNr++ ) {
            prt()
            delete tag2val
        }

        # save "insert_job" value
        tag = substr($1,1,length($1)-1)
        val = substr($0,length($1)+1,RSTART-(length($1)+2))
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",val)
        gsub(/^"|"$/,"",val)
        tag2val[tag] = val

        # update $0 to start with "job_type" to look like all other input
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+1)
    }

    {
        tag = val = $0
        sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
        gsub(/^"|"$/,"",val)
        tag2val[tag] = val
    }

    END { prt() }

    function prt(    tagNr,tag,val) {
        for ( tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++ ) {
            tag = tags[tagNr]
            val = tag2val[tag]
            gsub(/"/,"\"\"",val)
            printf "\"%s\"%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
' "${@:--}"

and this is what it outputs:
$ ./tst.sh test.txt
"insert_job","job_type","box_name","command","machine","owner","date_conditions","condition","run_calendar","exclude_calendar","days_of_week","run_window","start_times","start_mins","resources","profile","term_run_time","watch_file","watch_interval"
"Test_A","CMD","","sleep 3000","machine1","user1","1","","","","mo,tu,we,th,fr","","06:00,08:00,10:00,12:00,14:00,16:00","","","","1","",""
"Test_B","CMD","","echo","machine2","user2","0","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"Test_c","CMD","","sleep 10","machine3","user3","0","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"Test_d","CMD","","ls","machine4","user4","0","","","","","","","","","","","",""

when run on this input file with the smart quotes changed to Ascii double quotes:
$  cat test.txt
/* ----------------- Test_A ----------------- */

insert_job: Test_A  job_type: CMD
command: sleep 3000
machine: machine1
owner: user1
permission:
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: mo,tu,we,th,fr
start_times: "06:00,08:00,10:00,12:00,14:00,16:00"
term_run_time: 1
alarm_if_fail: 1
alarm_if_terminated: 1


/* ----------------- Test_B ----------------- */

insert_job: Test_B    job_type: CMD
command: echo
machine: machine2
owner: user2
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "Test"
std_out_file: "/tmp/$AUTO_JOB_NAME.$AUTORUN.out"
std_err_file: "/tmp/$AUTO_JOB_NAME.$AUTORUN.err"
max_run_alarm: 1
alarm_if_fail: 0
alarm_if_terminated: 0
send_notification: 1



/* ----------------- Test_c ----------------- */

insert_job: Test_c   job_type: CMD
command: sleep 10
machine: machine3
owner: user3
permission:
date_conditions: 0
alarm_if_fail: 0
alarm_if_terminated: 0


/* ----------------- Test_d ----------------- */

insert_job: Test_d   job_type: CMD
command: ls
machine: machine4
owner: user4
permission:
date_conditions: 0
alarm_if_fail: 1
alarm_if_terminated: 1

For more information on working with CSVs in awk see What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?.
